# Customization of the Height of a Pivot Item Link Line in Fluent UI

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

I'm trying to increase the height of the line on the selected Pivot item link in Microsoft's Fluent UI using React.

Here's a screenshot for the purposes of clarification:

[image]

The orange arrow is pointing to the blue line of which I would like to increase the height.

I have tried setting the styles attribute of the `Pivot` component but thus far have been unsuccessful.  Here's some code

```
const pivotStyles: Partial<IStyleSet<IPivotStyles>> = {
    link: { ? },
    linkContent: { ? }
};

<Pivot styles={pivotStyles} linkSize={PivotLinkSize.large}>
    <PivotItem headerText="Zane"></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem headerText="Kai"></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem headerText="Jay"></PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

I have experimented with different attributes of both `link` and `linkContent` but haven't found a way yet.  I believe what I'm trying to do is manipulate the [IStyle](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/references/istyle#IStyle) interface but I can't find details of the attributes of it.  The link there is very vague.  For example, what are all the available attributes of `link`, `linkContent`, etc.?

Any thoughts on this would be most appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was on the right track and just needed the exact fields.  Here's what ended up working:

```
const pivotStyles = {
  linkIsSelected: {
    selectors: {
      ':before': {
        height: '6px',   // was previously defaulted at 2px
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I scoured about 4.24 million sites to find this answer but here are some of the most helpful in case they are of interest:

- the actual source code of [Pivot.styles.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Pivot/Pivot.styles.ts)
- the Microsoft Fluent UI [Pivot Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pivot)

A deep examination of the classes using Chrome Dev Tools also helped.  ;)

Here's a picture of the end result:

[image: working image]

Comment: Thank you! made my day!!